# Is this a Potential code error or machine set up error? Not sure

Tags: r, h2o

I am working through section 19.2.3 of [HOML/autoencoders.html](https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/autoencoders.html) and found an error message pop up.

In section: 19.2.3 Visualizing the reconstruction, I found an error associated with the line:

```
# Predict reconstructed pixel values  
best_model_id <- grid_perf@model_ids[[1]]
```

after this line I get:

```
Error: object 'grid_perf' not found
```

Up to this point, I have followed the code from the Autoencoder section, should I look at my setup or is this a change in H2O.ai and code?

HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, there is no object `grid_perf` to call. It should be defined before that line runs.

From the document you are following, in section 19.2.2, it defines `ae_grid`:

```
ae_grid <- h2o.grid(
  algorithm = 'deeplearning',
  x = seq_along(features),
  training_frame = features,
  grid_id = 'autoencoder_grid',
  autoencoder = TRUE,
  activation = 'Tanh',
  hyper_params = hyper_grid,
  sparse = TRUE,
  ignore_const_cols = FALSE,
  seed = 123
)
```

Did you try defining `grid_perf`?

Then it calls it in section 19.2.3 `best_model_id <- ae_grid@model_ids[[1]]` which is what it looks like you are trying to replicate.